# How can give date format dd/mm/yyyy for the date column of an html table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am looking for how to give 'dd/mm/yyyy' format for the date column of the table

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public string FromDate { get; set; }
```

```html
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control date-input emphrs" })</td>
```

Comment: `FromDate` is a `string`. .NET doesn't know what characters represent the value for days, months, or years within a string, let alone how to transform them. I think you want `public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }`

Comment: Hello Did you tried the solution, let me know if you have any further concern on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

***Model:***

```
 public class DateFormaterModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public string FromDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public string ToDate { get; set; }
    }
```

***Controller:***

```
public IActionResult DateFormatter()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

***View:***

```
@model MVCApps.Models.DateFormaterModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "DateFormatter";
}

<h2>Date Formatter</h2>

<table id="tblEntry" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date From</th>
            <th>Date To</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @id = "fromDate", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker w-100"} })</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @id = "toDate", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker w-100" } })</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

***Output:***

[image]

> ***Note:*** You have missed this property `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` which would help to achive that. Additionally as [@LIama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/llama) already said `string` wouldn't act here accordingly. So `DateTime` would be identical. But `string` can also would work perfectly the way I shown you.

Hope it would help you to resolve your problem.